# GridSearchCV custom scorer to consider both train and test performance

Tags: gridsearchcv

Based on my current understanding, the standard use of GridSearchCV scorers ( through available options such as "f1_micro") aim to maximize the average **performance across validation folds**. However, in my problem I want to design a custom scorer that will consider both **average validation** and **average training** **performance**, using the trading folds for the latter. Is there a way to achieve this e.g. with a custom scorer?

As for the motivation, this feature could be used to design a scorer that aims  at a  high validation performance  that do not deviate too much from the training performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, you can achieve this by creating a custom scorer in scikit-learn. By default, the GridSearchCV scorer maximizes the average performance across validation folds, but you can define your own scorer to consider both the average validation and average training performance.

To create a custom scorer that combines both average validation and average training performance, you can define a function that takes the true labels, predicted labels, and model as input, and returns a score based on your desired criteria.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

def custom_scorer(estimator, X, y):
    # Calculate validation score (F1 score)
    y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
    validation_score = f1_score(y, y_pred, average='micro')
    
    # Calculate training score (F1 score)
    train_predictions = estimator.predict(X_train)
    training_score = f1_score(y_train, train_predictions, average='micro')
    
    # Combine validation and training scores (average)
    combined_score = (validation_score + training_score) / 2
    
    return combined_score
```

In this example, we use the F1 score as the performance metric, but you can replace it with any other metric that suits your needs. The `model` argument represents the current model being evaluated in the `GridSearchCV` cross-validation loop.

Once you have defined your custom scorer, you can pass it to the `scoring` parameter of `GridSearchCV` when initializing it:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Create the grid search object with your custom scorer
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=SVC(), param_grid=param_grid, scoring=custom_scorer)

grid_search.fit(X, y)
```

By using your custom scorer, the `GridSearchCV` will optimize the hyperparameters based on the combined score of both average validation and average training performance.

Comment: Ok, but  how is X_train and y_train passed to the customer scorer function? They are not in the function signature.

Comment: @Enk9456  
You have to split dataset into train and test  then `X_train` is define from global scope.
**note:** you can pass X_train and y_train into fit method of gridsearch.